# Como chamar um ajax dentro de outro?

Tags: javascript, ajax

preciso chamar outra requisição ajax dentro de uma condição. Mas o ajax de fora nao espera o de dentro termianr para finalizar. Exemplo:
Uso isso

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "MINHA_URL",
                        success: function (e) {
                        if(e == 'erro'){
                           $.ajax({
                               type: "GET",
                               url: "MINHA_SEGUNDA_URL",
                               success: function (f) {
                                  IMPRIMIE ALGUMA COISA
                               }
                       .....
```

O problema é que nao executacorretamente. Como proceder?

Comment: Nao sei qual versão do jQuery que está usando mas o comum é usar o `done` para executar algo quando a requisição for realmente concluída.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'MINHA_URL',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        html: 'Teste 1'
    },
    success: function(returnhtml) {
        $("#result").append($('</p>').html(returnhtml));
        $.ajax({
            url: 'MINHA_URL',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                html: 'Teste 2'
            },
            success: function(returnhtml) {
                $("#result").append($('</p>').html(returnhtml));
            }
        });

    }
});
```

`Resultado : <div id="result"><p>Teste 1</p> <p>Teste 2</p> </div>`

Exemplo prático: http://jsfiddle.net/qz02oukw/

Answer (score 0):

```
Mas o ajax de fora não espera o de dentro terminar para finalizar.
```

Não espera pois são requisições assíncronas.
Defina na chamada do ajax a option `async: false`

Comment: O problema é que {async: false} ja está obsoleto nas versoes mais novas do jquery!